# java.util.Timer - how to use properly?

Tags: java, android, timer, cpu-usage

I need a timer for my game: when the user taps the screen, timer should pause and resume. Firstly, I tried to create a `Timer` once, `MyTimerTask.cancel()` to pause it, `Timer.schedule(new MyTimerTask, ...)` to resume it. But task manager shows that when the timer is paused, my application spends a huge amount of CPU (I develop under Android). As I understand, `Timer` executes empty queue. Now I `.cancel()` and `.purge()` the `Timer` and re-create it, along `MyTimerTask`. Is it right way to use `Timer`? Or I don't understand something?

Comment: What do you mean by "the timer is paused"? Do you mean that you cancelled your task?

Comment: @salman.mirghasemi It does no matter to me. I just want `Timer` to stop calling `MyTimerTask`'s `run()` and continue doing it when I need.

Comment: If it is possible add your code to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just add an if statement in you main game loop like:

```
while(runMainLoop)
{
    if(gameIsNotPaused)
    {
    updatePhysics();
    doDraw();
    }
}
```

And then when the user presses the pause button, you just set gameIsNotPaused to false/true.

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to rewrite the game to use game loop. I thought that the timer would be enough, but...

Comment: Just keep in mind that you need the game loop to run in a separate thread so you don't block the UI thread.